# Return to Original Pivot Table View via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I understand that this is very complicated b/c pivot tables can be incredibly different depending on use case, but I was hoping to find a way that would allow me to essentially memorialize the current view of the Pivot Table, and then go back to it after I drill around. At the highest level, click a button that resets the pivot back to its original state when I opened the file.

I know there are probably several ways to approach this (including just copying to a new sheet), but I was hoping for a universal way to do it that didn't require the addition of a new sheet.

Thanks!
Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it wont be super easy.

I just used the macro recorder while building a simple pivot table from made up data. I got this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("A")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("B")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("C"), "Sum of C", xlSum
End Sub
```

From the recorded macro we can see that the Pivot table object has properties like PivotFields and DataFields. You'd have to loop through all the relevant items in the various properties in the PivotTable object, then store that data somewhere. Either by serializing it out to a hidden worksheet or by storing it in a global VBA variable.

Documentation on the [Pivot Table Object is available here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835831.aspx).